# Google Chrome flickers on Cinnamon, but not on Xfce

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, display

I am experiencing some flickering problems with Google Chrome (and Chromium, **but not on Firefox**) on certain websites. The thing is that the flickering manifests only on Cinnamon desktop environment, and not on Xfce.

Turning off hardware acceleration does not help: it turns the flickering into tearing.

Notes: Cinnamon was installed after Xfce, the Chrome-flickering issue is the only problem I am facing with Cinnamon. Also, I am using Bumblebee to run programs on nVidia graphics card on-demand, but since everything works well on Xfce, I am guessing that it's a (Cinnamon/Chrome)-related problem.

Here is the [inxi -Fxz output on Xfce](https://gist.github.com/alexandru-dinu/594ad0273dc330446c0e1e9819b0d6b7). I have observed that Cinnamon uses GTK3, whereas Xfce uses GTK2.

Any suggestions on how I can approach this issue, to at least find the culprit?

Comment: What are you really expecting? Don't use GTK3 based DE if it does not work for you, it's that simple. I presonally don't understand how can anyone stand GTK3, but that's unimportant.

Comment: @ajeh - do you mind elaborating that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this solves it: `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel`